# Python: How to check for RSS updates with feedparser and etags

Tags: python, rss, http-headers, etag, feedparser

I'm trying to skip over RSS feeds that have not been modified using feedparser and etags.
Following the guidelines of the documentation: http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/http-etag.html

```
import feedparser

d = feedparser.parse('http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/feed/')
d2 = feedparser.parse('http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/feed/', etag=d.etag)

print d2.status
```

This outputs:

```
200
```

Shouldn't this script return a 304?
My understanding is that when the RSS feed gets updated the etag changes and if they match then I should get a 304.

How come I am not getting my expected result?

Comment: Can't reproduce it on my machine. I get a `304` using feedparser-5.1.3 on Python 2.6

Comment: I am also using python 2.6 and feedparser-5.1.3, on Debian 6

Comment: Ah! Probably my organization's proxy does some caching and so I don't see the issue

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Apparently this server is configured to check 'If-Modified-Since' header. You need to pass last modified time as well:

```
>>> d = feedparser.parse('http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/feed/')
>>> feedparser.parse('http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/feed/', 
                     etag=d.etag, modified=d.modified).status
304
>>> feedparser.parse('http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/feed/', 
                     etag=d.etag).status
200
```

Comment: Well you are correct in saying that it works with the Modified header. But in this case you can take out the etag completely and it will return a 304. 
Although this works there a quite a bit of feeds that have etag headers and do not have modified headers. 
Is there any reason why the Etags are not working? Could it be related to my server that is making the requests?

Comment: Etag and last-modified headers are two independent caching techologies. Some servers use one of them, some might use both. If you want to support caching for all servers, you should emulate standard behavior of browsers. Modern browsers send both etag and if-modified-since headers, so you should do the same.